# How can I push route after saving data with Reactjs and Flux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactjs-flux

Here is my setup. I have a SPA using react, react-router, and flux. The "Projects" page lists project objects obtained from a network call. When the user clicks the "Add" button they are routed to the "New Project" page. Here they fill out a form.

When the users presses the "Save" button the form data is collected, validated, and passed to an action class. The action class uses a service to save the data over the network. When the action is complete the action class sends a dispatch notice. The project form component is listening and knows that the data has been saved. Now I want to route/nav to the "Projects" page but when I make the following call I get an error.

```
this.props.history.replaceState(null, "/projects");
```

Error:

```
Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.
```

Is there a simple way around this or a better way to handle the save & route change?

Here are my reactjs dependencies.

```
"react": "^0.14.6",
"react-dom": "^0.14.6",
"react-router": "^1.0.3",
```

Comment: `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` --> `browserHistory.push('/projects'`)

Comment: I tired but it failed. That must be an older (order newer) technique. I'll add the versions of libs to the description.

Comment: this.props.history.replaceState(null, "/projects"); works when used outside of the dispatch listener function. But within the dispatch listener function I get the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: You can only dispatch `actions` to the Redux store, you can't pass functions (unless you get into `redux-thunk` that said, changing browser locations shouldn't take place in a reducer, since a reducer should ONLY return state

Comment: After talking to others who have this same problem. The most common answer seems to be "Don't do that". In other words by using a popup instead of a different page for the entry form then the problem goes away because there is no need to change route only state. The listeners do what they need to do (like hide the popup because the "save" operation was successful).